# Cannot get data reader from RefCursor in ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-5, odp.net, ref-cursor

I have this code that runs an Oracle package:

```
        using (PedidoEntities db = new PedidoEntities())
        {
            OracleParameter p_usuario = new OracleParameter("p_usuario", OracleDbType.Int32);
            p_usuario.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; p_usuario.Value = usuario;
            OracleParameter p_oficinas = new OracleParameter("p_oficinas", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
            p_oficinas.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            string sql = @"begin
                             pqte_consultas.Pr_ObtieneOficinasUsuario(:p_usuario, :p_oficinas);
                           end;";
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, p_usuario, p_oficinas);

            OracleDataReader rdr = ((OracleRefCursor)p_oficinas.Value).GetDataReader();
            List<Oficina> oficinas = new List<Oficina>();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Oficina oficina = new Oficina()
                {
                    Value = rdr["oficina"].ToString(),
                    Text = rdr["descripcion"].ToString()
                };
                oficinas.Add(oficina);
            }

            return oficinas;
        }
```

p_oficinas is a RefCursor output parameter.

when I debug, that parameter actually contains a data reader after the pl/sql is executed, however, when I run

```
OracleDataReader rdr = ((OracleRefCursor)p_oficinas.Value).GetDataReader();
```

an exception is thrown telling that the connection is closed. In fact, when I watch the underlying connection property, it is actually closed, even when the data reader appears in opened state.

How can I do this?

Comment: You should close the OracleDataReader after you have used it. Also `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should use the Oracle drivers

Comment: i cannot called GetDataReader so I cannot close somethng what I don't have.... and I am using Oracle drivers (ODP.NET and Entity Framework)... what make you think I am using System.Data.OracleClient?

Comment: I have opened the connection explicitly by calling db.Database.Connection.Open() but connection get closed after  db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand call.

Comment: I have used ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Connection.Open(); just after "using" instruction and the connection continues opened. I used ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Connection.Close(); just before the "using" block ends. This works, however, I don't know if this the right solution.

Comment: Sorry, I was misinterpreting `**System.Data**.ParameterDirection`. But I think my first point is valid.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-refcursors-092375.html You can set up ODP.NET bind variables using this technique rather than using  ExecuteSqlCommand and it should work

Comment: There's more example code buried in this walkthough: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/2015/optimizing_data_access_performance_with_odpnet/optimizing%20data%20access%20performance%20with%20odpnet.html#section4